# Securing a web service that updates user details

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, encryption, ws-security

The web service(using POST) allows the requester to update details of a user.
The web service accepts the id of the user to be updated.

I think accpeting the id of the request as a parameter is risky. Someone could create a post request and
insert the id of any user and update the details of that user.

To ensure to an acceptable level that user details cannot be updated what are the options. Here is
what I think :

There is currently no security framework in place.

1. encrypt the request at the transport layer user SSL
2. encrypt just the id itself

Comment: You already tagged it: ws-security.

Comment: Do you use any security framework?

Comment: @Stefan I don't understand your comment, are you saying I should use SOAP instead of REST ?

Comment: @holmis83 there is currently no security in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `https` for secure transport is a good start.

Since you have tagged your question with "spring" and there is no security framework in place, I would suggest you take a look at [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/), which integrates nicely with Spring.